# ¿Como puedo actualizar el RecyclerView sin obtener el error Index Out Of Range? - Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, recyclerview

Tengo un News Feed que trabaja con `Lists` (Usuarios, Contenido, FechaHora, Imagenes, etc.) y que funciona muy bien.

El problema es al momento de `refrescar/actualizar` el `Feed / RecyclerView` (ya sea con un boton, o porque se gatillo el evento de 'registro agregado' en Firebase), me lanza el error de Index Out of Range en el `OnBindViewHolder` del adaptador.

Seguimiento de pila:

> android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition
> RecyclerView.java, line 5715 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter
> positionViewHolder{948cf82 position=3 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no
> parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{f1a7084 VFED.V...
> ........ 0,0-1080,1736 #7f0a0172 app:id/RecyclerNewsFeedI},
> adapter:crc64e276f6472b9ab7c6.FeedAdapter@24f017f,
> layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@6a2506d,
> context:android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@c3c21a0

De momento lo he manejado mostrando una animacion/splash/preloader en los 3 segundos que toma actualizar, pero he visto RecyclerViews que funcionan de maravilla solo apareciendo los nuevos registros (sea 1 u 11).

**EDITADO (Agregue el `OnBindViewHolder` del Adaptador):**

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            try
            {
                ActHolder hh = holder as ActHolder;  
                int X = position;                  

                    //Texto del CardView
                    hh.txtTitle.Text = VarGlobal.TextoActList[X];

                    //Imagen **//ERROR AQUI//**
                    if (VarGlobal.ImagenesActList[X] != null && VarGlobal.ImagenesActList[X] != "") 
                    {
                        //Descargando imagen.
                        ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(VarGlobal.ImagenesActList[X])
                        .Retry(10, 500)
                        .LoadingPlaceholder("Preloader", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
                        .ErrorPlaceholder("Preloader", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)                        
                        .Into(hh.imgIcono);
                        
                    }
                    else
                        ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(VarGlobal.gURLImage404)
                        .Retry(5, 450)
                        .LoadingPlaceholder("Preloader", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
                        .ErrorPlaceholder("Preloader", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
                        .Into(hh.imgIcono);                
                                
                Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "quicks.ttf");
                hh.txtTitle.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);

                hh.itemClickListener = this;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Ideas practicas?

Comment: Agrega tu adapter.

Comment: @Jorgesys listo.

Comment: agrega toda la clase adapter, hay que ver cómo refrescas la lista